# custom background not applying in spite of setting it in the admin panel of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

1. I applied the "custom background" to my theme by Appearance
   ->Background.But, nothing applied to my site(add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );).
2. But, its working fine with my default themes.
3. Need some help immediately.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help its an urgent task for me to complete by today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the "custom-background" class to my "body" tag.
Then, everything worked smoothly.